# How to pass dynamic parameter for events object of fullcalendar using json?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar with json feed, the code is as follows

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: {
            url: '/EventInfo/GetEventsByEmployee',
            cache: false,
            lazyFetching:true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                empId: $('#eventownerId').val()
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },               
        },
        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            displayDayEvents(date, allDay, jsEvent, view);
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.find('.fc-event-time').hide();
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
```

Here I am passing selected value of drop down control through data field as "empId: $('#eventownerId').val()". It returns correct data at page load.
Now I want to reload the calendar data when user selects option from drop down list.
for this purpose I used following code

```
$('#eventownerId').change(function (e) {            
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');            
    });
```

But refetch calls the json method with old data (i.e. initial value of drop down control), even selected value of drop down has been changed.
How I can pass current value of drop down control and reload the fullcalendar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed the problem by calling destroy of fullcalendar, as follows

```
$('#dropdownlistId').change(function (e) {            
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');           
        RenderCalendar($(this).val());
    });
```

and RenderCalendar() is

```
function RenderCalendar(eId) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: {
            url: '/EventInfo/GetEventsByEmployee',
            cache: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                empId: eId
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        },
        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            displayDayEvents(date, allDay, jsEvent, view);
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.find('.fc-event-time').hide();
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
}
```

Using this I managed the problem but not sure this is correct way of doing it. i.e. destroying and recreating the calendar. I am still searching for correct way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried get the id in a var and then do it like this?

```
var id = $('#eventownerId').val(); //outside

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: {
        url: '/EventInfo/GetEventsByEmployee',
        cache: false,
        lazyFetching:true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            empId: id // var in here
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },               
    },
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        displayDayEvents(date, allDay, jsEvent, view);
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-event-time').hide();
        element.attr('title', event.tip);
    }
});
```

Another thing check if the ID is actually getting the diferent id from dropdown. Can you show the GetEventsByEmployee method? Cheers

Comment: I tried way of keeping 'var id' outside, but it doesn't work. Also drop down giving different value on each selection. Problem is $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents') calling GetEventsByEmployee() method with initial (load time) drop down value. Code for GetEventsByEmployee()`public JsonResult GetEventsByEmployee(double start, double end, int empId)
{         
  var startDateTime = FromUnixTimestamp(start);
  var endDateTime = FromUnixTimestamp(end);
  //some code to fetch data from db
  return Json(eventList.ToArray(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}`